# How to target Facebook users with products they viewed without purchasing

Tags: php, facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to work out this issue for some weeks now. I even contacted Facebook but they said to contact Stack Overflow.

How are you successfully targeting Facebook visitors with the same product after they viewed it and left from your website?

For example: Mr. A visits example.com which is an e-commerce site. Views Product A then goes to Product B and then exits from the site. The next day Mr. A will see Product B in the Right Column/News Feed Ads.

I have a hunch that it has something to do with firing the Custom Audience Pixel with the Product B id data but not sure how to implement that code in the FB Custom Audience Pixel.

Also note: I have already configured the Product Feed and the product catalog work is all done.

Comment: have you tried contacting `google adwords`? I think they are the one who manages all these... btw all these are due to browser cookies saved in user's computer

Answer (score 1):

I think it's funny that Facebook actually seems to try to outsource its product support to StackOverflow...

Did you have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-audiences/v2.3

You need to use the *Custom Audience Pixel* as described at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/website-custom-audiences/getting-started

with the events described in the first link. E.g. upon a product view in your website, a product view content event should be triggered:

```
window._fbq.push(['track', 'ViewContent', {
  content_ids: ['<product_id>'],
  content_type: 'product'
}]);
```

You then should be able to build custom audiences for your Ads.

Comment: Yups! I have gone through the Links you have mentioned but I can't figure it out. Its really confusing! Have you implemented this technique? If yes then can you show me a sample code please?